# When is $\sin^3(x) >\cos^3(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Solve the following inequality.
>   $$\sin^3(x) >\cos^3(x).$$

How would you go about solving this inequality?

I have tried factorisation already, using the difference of cubes, but it did not lead to much at all.

Also, given that the cubic power does not really alter the signs of sine and cosine, why are you not allowed to take the cubic root on both sides and compare sine and cosine afterwards?
Thank you.

Comment: note that $x^3>y^3 \iff x>y$.

Comment: or do you mean $\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))>\cos(\cos(\cos(x)))$?

Comment: Not at all, I meant the first one.

Comment: Which means I should be able to simply take the cubic root of on both sides?

Comment: yes, $t\mapsto \sqrt[3]{t}$ is a strictly increasing function.

Comment: The solution to the exercise is, however, pi/4 + 2kpi < x < 5/4pi + 2kpi.

Comment: indeed, these are the intervals where $\sin(x)>\cos(x)$ (you can plot to check).

Comment: My bad, they actually are. Turns out I multiplied and compared the signs of the functions, rather than the actual values. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $t\mapsto t^3$ is **continuous** and strictly **increasing** we have $x<y\iff x^3<y^3$ and so $\sin(x)^3>\cos(x)^3\iff\sin(x)>\cos(x)$.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I thought. The solution to the exercise is, however, pi/4 + 2kpi < x < 5/4pi + 2kpi.

Comment: Indeed, these are the intervals where $\sin(x)>\cos(x)$ [WA plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin(x),+cos(x),+sin(x)%5E3,+cos(x)%5E3).

Answer (score 2):

The hardest part:

We need to solve $$\sin{x}>\cos{x}$$ or
$$\sin{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\cos{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}>0$$ or
$$\sin\left(x-45^{\circ}\right)>0$$ or
$$360^{\circ}k<x-45^{\circ}<180^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k,$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$ or

$$45^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k<x<225^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k.$$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

not that $$\sin^3(x)-\cos^3(x)=(\sin(x)-\cos(x))(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+\sin(x)\cos(x))$$ and so you have to solve $$\sin(x)>\cos(x)$$

Comment: that is true, you say something without a proof

Comment: yes i have made a typo, since errare humanum est

Comment: don't you think that i know this factorization?

Answer (score 1):

$$
X^3-Y^3>0 \iff (X-Y)(X^2+XY+Y^2)>0
$$
and $(X^2+XY+Y^2)$ is always positive.

So, yes, we are allowed to take the cubic root of both sides.